# Spark Structured-Streaming Error:-pyspark.sql.utils.StreamingQueryException: 'assertion failed: Invalid batch:

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a Spark Structured-Streaming application, which reads JSON data from s3 and does some transformations and writes it back to s3.

While running the application, sometimes the job errors out and re-attempts (without any visible loss or data corruption- so that everything seems fine), but the error message provided is not very descriptive

Below is the error message:

```
pyspark.sql.utils.StreamingQueryException: u'assertion failed: Invalid batch: _ra_guest_gid#1883,_ra_sess_ts#1884,_ra_evt_ts#1885,event#1886,brand#1887,category#1888,funding_daysRemaining#1889,funding_dollarsRemaining#1890,funding_goal#1891,funding_totalBackers#1892L,funding_totalFunded#1893,id#1894,name#1895,price#1896,projectInfo_memberExclusive#1897,projectInfo_memberExclusiveHoursRemaining#1898,projectInfo_numberOfEpisodes#1899,projectInfo_projectState#1900,variant#1901 != _ra_guest_gid#2627,_ra_sess_ts#2628,_
```

My guess is this may have something to do with column mismatches, where

1. The incoming JSON record does not conform to the schema.
2. Or the datatype of the incoming JSON record may not match the data type provided in schema.

But I'm not sure how to pinpoint which record or which particular field causes the error.

Any help or suggestions here on what the error means or how I could log the error in a better way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i have figured out the issue, it is not related to schema mismatch.
What was happening in my case is that i have two streaming operations running in parallel.

1)reading raw incoming data from an S3 bucket, then doing some operation and writing it back to S3 in output folder 'a'

2)reading the processed streaming data from folder 'a' (step1) and then again doing some operation and writing back to S3 in output folder 'b'

Now as per my observations if i run the above steps individually then it works fine, but if i run them together i get the error

'pyspark.sql.utils.StreamingQueryException: u'assertion failed: Invalid batch: '

so i think it has trouble when it tries to read and write from same location i.e. the destination of one stream is the  source of another stream